# Pyinstaller onefile doesn't run when adding data files except when launched from command prompt

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I've been trying a number of solutions found on this site and others but nothing seems to work. The issue is when trying to compile with --onefile. The resulting executable crashes saying: "Failed to execute script". I managed to catch the output in windowed mode trying to run onefile.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mainwindow.ui'
```

Seems like the files added aren't getting attached properly when running --onefile/-F.

I've edited my spec file to include the files

```
datas=[ ( '//network/power_tool/mainwindow.ui' , '.'),
                ( '//network/power_tool/comsettings.ui' , '.')],
```

It runs fine if I don't enable onefile and runs fine if I open the executable from a command prompt window but won't launch independently. What step am I missing?